# Animate button rotation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to animate rotation of icon inside custom button to 180 degree on each press. I'm bit confused from the flutter documentation. I know I should use `RotationTransition` but I just can not find out how.. Here is my button

```
     SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: Size(50, 50),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              splashColor: Colors.black12,
              child: RotationTransition(. //<== that is where I get
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.filter_list, //rotate this icon
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need a Stateful widget with an AnimationController which creates controls the animation. It's important to create that controller on the `initState()` method, and **dispose** it on the `dispose()` method to prevent possible errors.

Once you have the controller, you can use a bool to store the rotation direction and an Animation controlled by the Animation controller to rotate the widget. First, it goes from 0 to 0.5, and then from 0.5 to 1.

The code can be like this. You can also take a look at [this](https://codepen.io/Javierd/pen/GRoMgxz) codepen I created for the example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> 
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  
  bool dir = true;
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose(){
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _animation = Tween<double>(
      begin: dir ? 0:0.5, 
      end: dir ? 0.5:1
    ).animate(_controller);
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RotationTransition(
          turns: _animation,
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Rotate"),
              onPressed: (){
                _controller.forward(
                  from: 0
                );
                setState(() {dir = !dir;});
              
              }
            )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just noticed that on fist click after hot restart it rotate 360 degree.. Do you have the same behaviour or am I doing something wrong?